# Ext.grid.View lost configurationOptions in ext 4 (autoFill)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In one ext3 application of mine i'm using these parameters for GridView:

autoFill: true,     //makes all columns together as wide as the hole table
forceFit: true,     //makes all columns together as wide as the hole table
scrollOffset: 0     //removes the space reserved for the scrollbar when there is no scrollbar

unfortunately i can't find them (or anything equivalent in ext4 anymore). Does anyone knows how these propertys has been replaced in the new Ext.grid.View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ExtJS4, the columns are laid out using [Ext.layout.container.HBox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox) layout. 
So,

- `autoFill: true` - You don't need this as long as you have **`flex:1` for at least one of the column configurations**
- `forceFit: true` not required (you will see a horizontal scroll bar below your grid if you specify absolute `width` for columns that together exceeds the total grid width. But this was true for v3 as well.
- You don't need `scrollOffset:0` anymore. This happens automagically now.